# Scalable "styles" on objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I would like to model a house like attached and have styles that can be repeated on objects throughout. Thinking like CSS for a blender object. For example, this house has like 10 different roof sections that all have the same pitch and fascia detail. I could draw up one roof detail the way I want it and then just use scaled linked duplicates, but I don't want to scale the dimensions of the fascia boards. Or the windows can be varying sizes but the window trim will always be 6inches at the top of the window and 3 inches on the sides and bottoms. Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished? I'd really like it to be a style that could be edited and re-applied throughout later in case I decide to change an element.

Thanks  [image: H]

Comment: Blender's [link functionality](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/linked_libraries.html?highlight=append) would be a start, but it "freezes" your objects in place. You cannot duplicate, move, rotate or resize them in any form. The only part that would come close to what you are looking for, are shared materials.

Comment: Have a look at the archimesh and archipack addons. These provide building components that can also be dynamically edited after being created.